# dplyr 0.7 tidy eval: convert character variables to factors

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I have a dataset with many variables, some of them are character variables, which I would like to convert to factors. Since there are many variables to convert, I would like to do this using the new *tidy eval* functionality from `dplyr_0.7`. Here is a minimal example from my data:

```
data <- data.frame(factor1 = c("K", "V"), 
                   factor2 = c("E", "K"), 
                   other_var = 1:2, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I have a named list containing a `data.frame` for each variable which I want to convert. These `data.frame`s in the list all have the same structure which can be seen in this example:

```
codelist_list <- list(factor1 = data.frame(Code = c("K", "V"), 
                                           Bezeichnung = c("Kauf", "Verkauf"), 
                                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                      factor2 = data.frame(Code = c("E", "K"), 
                                           Bezeichnung = c("Eigengeschaeft", "Kundengeschaeft"), 
                                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

---

What I do **not** want to do is to define the factors like this for each variable:

```
mutate(df, factor1 = factor(factor1, 
                            levels = codelist_list[["factor1"]][["Code"]],
                            labels = codelist_list[["factor1"]][["Bezeichnung"]]))
```

---

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
convert_factors <- function(variable, df) {
  factor_variable <- enquo(variable)
  df %>% 
    mutate(!!quo_name(factor_variable) := factor(!!quo_name(factor_variable), 
                                                 levels = codelist_list[[variable]][["Code"]],
                                                 labels = codelist_list[[variable]][["Bezeichnung"]]))
}
```

In a first step, I want to check if my function `convert_factors()` works properly by calling `convert_factors("factor1", data)` which returns

```
  factor1 factor2 other_var
1    <NA>       E         1
2    <NA>       K         2
```

The variable does not show the value labels, but is replaced by `NA` instead.

The ultimate goal would be to `map` over all variables which I want to convert. Here, I tried `map(c("factor1", "factor2"), convert_factors, df = data)`, which returned

> Error in (function (x, strict = TRUE)  : the argument has already been evaluated

I tried to follow the instructions from http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html, but this is all I came up with.

Does anyone know where the problem is (and hopefully explain my error to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this with `mutate_at`, using the `.` coding within `funs` to apply a function to multiple columns at once.

This approach still involves using `tidyeval` to pull the correct list from `codelist_list` while referring to the variable via `.`.

```
mutate_at(data, c("factor1", "factor2"), 
          funs( factor(., levels = codelist_list[[quo_name(quo(.))]][["Code"]],
                      labels = codelist_list[[quo_name(quo(.))]][["Bezeichnung"]]) ) )

  factor1         factor2 other_var
1    Kauf  Eigengeschaeft         1
2 Verkauf Kundengeschaeft         2
```

If you wanted to make a function to pass to `mutate_at`, you can do so, with a few slight changes.

```
convert_factors = function(variable) {
     var2 = enquo(variable)
     factor(variable, levels = codelist_list[[quo_name(var2)]][["Code"]],
            labels = codelist_list[[quo_name(var2)]][["Bezeichnung"]]) 
}

mutate_at(data, c("factor1", "factor2"), convert_factors)

 factor1         factor2 other_var
1    Kauf  Eigengeschaeft         1
2 Verkauf Kundengeschaeft         2
```

Comment: aosmith, just for my own understanding: How would this look like, if I would like to define a function, which then would be called in `mutate_at`. Then, would one have to change `quo_name`... and so on?

Comment: @der_grund See edit for one option.  The main switch is to using `enquo`.  `quo_name` is still used to transform a quoted symbol to a string for pulling out the appropriate element from the list.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mixed up quosures and strings:

1. In you funtion,`variable` is a string, not an expression. So you should convert it to quo with `rlang::sym`, instead of `enquo`.
2. `quo_name` is used to convert an expression to string. As `variable` is already a string, you can directly do `!!variable` on rhs (right hand side) in `mutate`.
3. at lhs in `mutate` you need to unquo `factor_variable` with `!!` instead of trying to convert it to a string with `quo_name`.

After correcting for the above errors, you function will work:

```
convert_factors <- function(variable, df) {
    factor_variable <- rlang::sym(variable)
    df %>% 
        mutate(!!variable := factor(
            !!factor_variable, 
            levels = codelist_list[[variable]][["Code"]],
            labels = codelist_list[[variable]][["Bezeichnung"]]))
}

# > convert_factors('factor1', data)
#   factor1 factor2 other_var
# 1    Kauf       E         1
# 2 Verkauf       K         2
```

Here is what I try:

```
params <- lapply(codelist_list, setNames, nm = c('levels', 'labels'))

convert_factors <- function(variable, df) {
    factor_variable <- rlang::sym(variable)
    factor_param <- c(list(factor_variable), params[[variable]])

    df %>% mutate(!!variable := do.call(factor, factor_param))
}

convert_factors('factor1', data)
#   factor1 factor2 other_var
# 1    Kauf       E         1
# 2 Verkauf       K         2
```

Comment: Nice! I was also trying to answer the question but I didn't know about rlang::sym yet so it was too difficult to me. Nice that I got to learn that one, I was struggling with a similar thing today.. I was thinking about passing down the respective element of codelist as well to make the function self-contained but this is already a super nice solution so I'll rather continue with my MA thesis.. ;)

Comment: @friep, `sym` is a handy function to convert a string to a quo. `quo`,`enquo`, `quo_name`, are all from `rlang`. I learned this function from community. Good luck with your thesis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know about `sym()` before. However, this is no solution for my "ultimate goal" as I stated it in the question. I overlooked that I needed `mutate_at` to convert all variables in the same `data.frame`, not one in each resulting one.

Answer (score 2):

Nice solution of mt1022 using tidy eval and dplyr. However, this task could be accomplished unsing only base-R:

```
data[,names(codelist_list)] <- lapply(names(codelist_list), function(x) 
  data[,x] <- factor(data[,x],
                     levels = codelist_list[[x]][["Code"]],
                     labels = codelist_list[[x]][["Bezeichnung"]]))
```

Comment: Very nice! It was not apparent to me that the base-R notation can handle this without any specific add-ons. This looks very clean.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just using strings and SE functions (the factor constructor), you don't need expressions or quosures. Just use name-unquoting with `:=`

```
convert_factors <- function(variable, df) {
  factor <- factor(variable,
    levels = codelist_list[[variable]][["Code"]],
    labels = codelist_list[[variable]][["Bezeichnung"]]
  )
  mutate(df, !! variable := factor)
}

map(c("factor1", "factor2"), convert_factors, df = data)
```